# Cambiar de JS a jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Por favor, necesito cambiar o convertir este JavaScript a jQuery. No puedo hacer, no conozco JavaScript a este nivel.

```
(function() {
 let video = document.querySelector(".video");  
 let bar = document.querySelector(".bar");

 function events() {
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateTime);
} events();

 function updateTime() {
  let curTime = video.currentTime;
  let duration = video.duration;
  let persentage = (curTime * 100) / duration;  
  bar.style.width = persentage + "%";
 };

})();
```

Comment: Disculpa si la pregunta suena tonta o sin sentido, pero, ¿por qué quieres cambiar a jQuery? ¿No funciona ese código? jQuery no es la solución. ¿Sí funciona? jQuery no es necesario. En fin, te ayudo con el evento: `$('.video').on('timeupdate', updateTime);` y tiempo actual: `let curTime = $('.video')[0].currentTime;`

Comment: Gracias. Es que estoy usando la librería jQuery. Sólo eso.

Comment: Aplica el principio #1 de la ingeniería: Si funciona **no lo toques**. No tienes que _cambiarlo_ a _jQuery_, que al final, si funciona en javascript plano, dejalo así.

Comment: @jachguate esta bien,, pero no es aplicable a todo, ya que podrias no saber su funcionamiento o que pasa si el codigo es espagueti, seria mejor arreglarlo. Esto solo es un comentario, entiendo tu punto de vista en esta situacion

Comment: @Cristian, no digo que nunca se toque, pero que si ahora vamos a usar x biblioteca, no me parece motivo suficiente, ni hace falta _traducir_ todo... tampoco estoy entrando a valorar si la función está bien hecha... obviamente si no lo está, habrá que corregirla u optimizarla, pero sospecho que la pregunta estaría planteada en otros términos si ese fuera el caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  const video = $(".video");
  const bar = $(".bar");
  video.bind("timeupdate", function(){
    let curTime = this.currentTime;
    let duration = this.duration;
    let persentage = (curTime * 100) / duration;
    bar.css("width", `${persentage}%`);
  });
});
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Qué diferencia hay entre let, const y var ..? Todos da igual

Comment: La diferencia radica en el "scope" o "alcance" de la variable, y en si la variable cambia o no. Por ejemplo: let y var son parecidas en ser variables que cambian, mientras que const nunca cambia, var podría considerarse obsoleta en nuevo JS y se reemplaza con let